# Problem in implementing my own switch class

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement a custom switch case just for fun..

The approach is that I have created a class that inherits a dictionary object

```
public class MySwitch<T> : Dictionary<string, Func<T>> 
    {
        public T Execute(string key)
        {
            if (this.ContainsKey(key)) return this[key]();
            else return default(T);
        } 
    }
```

And I am using as under

```
 new MySwitch<int>
    {
    { "case 1",  ()=> MessageBox.Show("From1") },
    { "case 2..10",  ()=>MessageBox.Show("From 2 to 10") },               
    }.Execute("case 2..10");
```

But if I specify **"case 2"** it gives a default value as the key is not in the dictionary.

The whole purpose of making **"case 2..10 "** is that if the user enters anything between **case 2 to case 10**, it will execute the same value.

Could anyone please help me in solving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The string "case 2..10" is stored in the dictionary object and the only way contains key returns ture is if you supply exactly that string.  meaning you would have to pass the exact string "case 2..10" to containskey to return true.

Answer (score 0):

My adice would be to look at the specification pattern.

You can have each function have one or more specification attached to it and then execute the relevant function (or functions if you want).

In short:

```
public interface ISpecification<T>
{
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(T item);
}
```

And a specific implementation:

```
public class IntegerRangeSpecification : ISpecification<int>
{
    private readonly int min;
    private readonly int max;

    public IntegerRangeSpecification(int min, int max)
    {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(int item)
    {
        return (item >= min) && (item <= max);
    }
}
```

Of course you would rather have `RangeSpecification<T> : ISpecification<T>` but that requires some more effort/design (such as `where T : IComparable`).

Anyway, I hope that gets you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

First you probably want to encapsulate a dictionary rather than extend a dictionary as I doubt you want all the methods of a dictionary in your switch class.

Second you will need to parse your case strings apart and add your own keys to the dictionary.  The approach of using strings as keys strikes me as not the best of ideas.  By using strings as your keys you are requiring that the keys match exactly.  If you made your dictionary use integer keys and you changed how it was initialized.  Keeping with the the spirit of your switch you could do something like this:

```
public class Switch<T>
{
    private Dictionary<int, Func<T>> _switch = new Dictionary<int, Func<T>>();
    private Func<T> _defaultFunc;

    public Switch(Func<T> defaultFunc)
    {
        _defaultFunc = defaultFunc;
    }


    public void AddCase(Func<T> func, params int[] cases)
    {
        foreach (int caseID in cases)
        {
            _switch[caseID] = func;
        }
    }

    public void AddCase( int beginRange, int endRange, Func<T> func)
    {
        for (int i = beginRange; i <= endRange; i++)
        {
            _switch[i] = func;
        }
    }

    public T Execute(int caseID)
    {
        Func<T> func;
        if(_switch.TryGetValue(caseID, out func)){
            return func();
        }else{
           return _defaultFunc();
        }
    }
}
```

Which could be used like this:

```
Switch<int> mySwitch = new Switch<int>(() => {Console.WriteLine("Default"); return 0;});
mySwitch.AddCase(() => { Console.WriteLine("1"); return 1; }, 1);
mySwitch.AddCase(2, 10, () => { Console.WriteLine("2 through 10"); return 1; });

mySwitch.AddCase(() => { Console.WriteLine("11, 15, 17"); return 2; }, 11, 15, 17);

mySwitch.Execute(1);
mySwitch.Execute(2);
mySwitch.Execute(3);
mySwitch.Execute(4);
mySwitch.Execute(11);
mySwitch.Execute(12);
mySwitch.Execute(15);
```

There are a bunch of different ways you can accomplish what you want.  Hope this helps some